# The grid.rect function will always cover the previous image

Tags: r

These are the codes from the book "R Graphic"(Third Edition).

```
library(grid)

pushViewport(plotViewport(c(5,4,2,2)))
pushViewport(dataViewport(pressure$temperature,
                          pressure$pressure,
                          name = "plotRegion"))

grid.rect()
grid.xaxis()
grid.yaxis()
grid.points(pressure$temperature, pressure$pressure,
            name = "dataSymbols")

grid.text("temperature", y = unit(-3, "line"))

grid.text("pressure", x = unit(-3, "line"), rot = 90)

#modify
grid.edit("dataSymbols", pch = 2)


upViewport(2)
grid.rect(gp = gpar(lty = "dashed"),draw = 1)
```

I am studying the grid package, and I am confused about the use of the grid.rect() function. My R version is 3.6.0.

The grid.rect function will always cover the previous image, what's the matter?